# How to return a HTML page from struts.xml itself without going to an action?

Tags: java, html, struts2, static, static-pages

If a request is made to a HTML page, how to return it directly from `struts.xml` without going to an action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an action that has a result in the `struts.xml` but doesn't have a `class`, i.e.

```
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">

<action name="index">
      <result name="myPage">/path/to/page.html</result>
</action>
```

You could also create a global result, that could be found from any action, i.e

```
<global-results>
      <result name="myPage">/path/to/page.html</result>
</global-results>

<action name="index"/>
```

You could create an interceptor that returns a result while intercepting and action. These are essential elements of the configuration that invoke a dispatcher to forward to requested page.